# Get user's Info from post request of Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, nodemailer, web-development-server

i am using for our project in company the nodemailer, its working perfectly 
fine.

I am wondering if its possible to get user's info automatically from the post request. for example i need to get the html variable like this:

html: 'Hello i am  `${request.username}` i sent this email to you' 
this is how i need my request looks like:

```js
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'servername.com',
port: 25,
debug: true,
logger:true,
secure: false,
});
// i need the mail options like the following
var mailOptions = {
from: 'MYEMAIL@COMPANYNAME.com', // sender address (who sends)
to: 'MYEMAIL@COMPANYNAME.com', // list of receivers (who receives)
subject: 'this email sent from ${request.username} ', // Subject line
text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
html: 'this email sent from ${request.username}' 
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
if(error){
return console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible (atleast ethically) unless you have username and email mapping available. But still to add a personal touch to email you can use part before "@" i.e. take this email for instance "your_name@domain.com", you can send email as
${request.username} will be "your_name"

Comment: that made sense

Comment: If it helps you make sure to upvote and mark asnwer.

Comment: i have leas than 15 reputation therefore i cannot upvote it